# Autofilter data according to entered cell values with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to make an equipment selector. I have three rows, one for name/type of equipment, one for flow capacity and one for the pressure/head capacity of the equipment. See below:

[image: My List]

I want to make a filter which depends on two cell values. I have an individual cells, one for Flow Input (cell F2) and one for Head Input (cell G2).

[image: My Input]

What I need is:
When I enter a value in the Flow Input and in the Head input (F2 & G2), the list will be filtered according to the entered values with the names of filtered equipment still showing.

I hope I have cleared my idea and that you understand what I need.

If you could help me I would be grateful.
Thank you

Comment: This should be possible with Excels *advanced filters* if you can change your sheet layout a bit. See [Excel Easy - Advanced Filter](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/advanced-filter.html) for a detailed tutorial about this and how your sheet layout should look like to achieve this.

Comment: Also, if you make your list a data table you could use  slicers, which would allow to filter ranges as well.

Comment: Thanks guys but I am kind of a learner. do you have some video/picture tutorial that I can look at?

Comment: @musicArabic just click that link in my first comment for a tutorial.

Comment: Do you want to achieve this with VBA or just use built-in formulas?